# numpy: broadcast matrix multiply accross array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a `3xN` array, conceptually an array of `N` 3-vectors, I want to construct the 
array which results from matrix multiplying a given `3x3` matrix with each column of the 
array.  Is there a good way to do this in a vectorized manner?

Currently, my problem is `3xN`, but I may need to consider `3xNxM` (or more) in the future.

Loopy approach

```
U=numpy.rand( [3,24] )

R=numpy.eye(3) # placeholder

for i in xrange( U.shape[1]):
    U[:,i]=numpy.dot( R, U[:,i] )
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081723/553404

Comment: @MrE that answer is pretty good, and for my shape (3xN) I avoid the transposes you mentioned there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using np.einsum function you can do it even for the multi dimension problem:

```
U = np.random.rand(3,24,5) 
R = np.eye(3,3)
result = np.einsum( "ijk,il", U,R )
```

The notation is a little tricky: the string you give first states the indeces of the dimensions of the arrays; so for U the indeces ijk are the running indeces for each dimension. It follows the einstein summation convention so indeces that have the same letter in the string will be summed over. For details read [ScipyDocs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). I'm sure in your case the dot is faster, because there is less overhead and it will probably use some blas routine, but as you stated that you want to expand to even more dimensions this might be the way to go.

Comment: In actual benchmarks, einsum pulls ahead quite often. Especially in cases such as these, involving contractions over small dimensions. I imagine BLAS is invoked by means of the gufunc mechanism; that is, a separate BLAS call on each tiny submatrix. In situations such as these, it is BLAS which will suffer due to an O(N) overhead, which quickly overwhelms the O(1) overhead of einsum.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can simply call `np.dot(R, U)` and it will work:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

U = np.random.rand(3,24) 
R = np.random.rand(3,3)

result = np.empty_like(U)

for i in range( U.shape[1]): 
    result[:,i] = np.dot(R, U[:,i])

print result

print np.allclose(result, np.dot(R, U))
```

For the `(3xNxM)` case you can reshape to (3x(N.M)), `dot` and reshape the result back, similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081723/553404)

Comment: I think using np.dot when you can is actually the way to go because it often makes use of really fast libraries such as Blas or Lapack that are higly optimized.