# Why does NumPy matrix multiply broadcast work in one direction but not in the transposed direction?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Consider the following matrix product between two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(2,10,10)                                             
B = np.random.rand(2,2)                                                 
C = A.T @ B
```

...goes fine. I think of the above as a 1-by-2 times 2-by-2 vector-matrix product broadcast over the 10-by-10 2nd and 3rd dimensions of A. Inspection of the result `C` confirms this intuition; `np.allclose(C[i,j], A.T[i,j] @ B)` for all `i`, `j`.

Now mathematically, I should be able to compute  `C.T` as well as: `B.T @ A`, but:

```
B.T @ A                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ffdbb14ca160> in <module>
----> 1 B.T @ A

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 10 is different from 2)
```

So broadcast-wise, a 10-by-10-by-2 tensor and a 2-by-2 matrix are compatible with respect to matrix product, but a 2-by-2 matrix and 2-by-10-by-10 tensor are not?

**Bonus info:** I want to be able to compute the "quadratic product" `A.T @ B @ A` and it really annoys me to have to write for-loops to manually "broadcast" over one of the dimensions. It feels like it should be possible to do this more elegantly. I am pretty experienced with Python and NumPy, but I rarely go beyond two-dimensional arrays.

What am I missing here? Is there something about the way transpose operates on tensors in NumPy that I do not understand?

Comment: The catcg phrase - last of A pairs with the 2nd to the last of B.  The first dim of a 3d is a 'batch' dimension.

Comment: I think I found a hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22973830/865169. It seems `np.einsum` can do the job: `C_transpose = np.einsum('ij,jkl', B.T, A)`
I have just still not figured out to configure `np.einsum` to compute `A.T @ B @ A` which is my ultimate goal.

Comment: `einsum` can have more than two terms: `np.einsum('i...,ij,j...',A,B,A)` note the use of Ellipsis for dimensions you want aligned but not summed over.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [194]: A = np.random.rand(2,10,10)                                           
     ...:    
     ...: B = np.random.rand(2,2)                                               
In [196]: A.T.shape                                                             
Out[196]: (10, 10, 2)

In [197]: C = A.T @ B                                                           
In [198]: C.shape                                                               
Out[198]: (10, 10, 2)
```

The `einsum` equivalent is:

```
In [199]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl',A.T,B),C)                         
Out[199]: True
```

or incorporating the transpose into the indexing:

```
In [200]: np.allclose(np.einsum('kji,kl->ijl',A,B),C)                           
Out[200]: True
```

Note that `k` is the summed dimension.  `j` and `l` are other `dot` dimensions.  `i` is a kind of 'batch' dimension.

Or as you explain `np.einsum('k,kl->l', A.T[i,j], B)`

To get `C.T`, the `einsum` result indices should be `lji`, or `lk,jki->lji`:

```
In [201]: np.allclose(np.einsum('lk,jki->lji', B.T, A.transpose(1,0,2)), C.T)      
Out[201]: True

In [226]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', B.T, A), C.T)                       
Out[226]: True
```

Matching [201] with `@` requires a further transpose:

```
In [225]: np.allclose((B.T@(A.transpose(1,0,2))).transpose(1,0,2), C.T)          
Out[225]: True
```

With `einsum` when can place the axes in any order, but with `matmul`, the order is fixed `(batch, i, k)@(batch, k, l) -> (batch, i, l)` (where the `batch` dimensions can be broadcast).

Your example might be easier if `A` had shape (2,10,9) and `B` (2,3), with `C` resulting in (9,10,3)

```
In [229]: A = np.random.rand(2,10,9); B = np.random.rand(2,3)                   
In [230]: C = A.T @ B                                                           
In [231]: C.shape                                                               
Out[231]: (9, 10, 3)
In [232]: C.T.shape                                                             
Out[232]: (3, 10, 9)

In [234]: ((B.T) @ (A.transpose(1,0,2))).shape                                    
Out[234]: (10, 3, 9)
In [235]: ((B.T) @ (A.transpose(1,0,2))).transpose(1,0,2).shape                   
Out[235]: (3, 10, 9)
In [236]: np.allclose(((B.T) @ (A.transpose(1,0,2))).transpose(1,0,2), C.T)        
Out[236]: True
```