# Numpy: Multiply a matrix with an array of vectors

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm having a hard time getting into numpy. What I want in the end is a simple quiver plot of vectors that have been transformed by a matrix. I've read many times to just use arrays for matrices, fair enough. And I've got a meshgrid for x and y coordinates

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid( np.arange(0,10,2),np.arange(0,10,1) )
a = np.array([[1,0],[0,1.1]])
```

But even after googling and trying for over two hours, I can't get the resulting vectors from the matrix multiplication of `a` and each of those vectors. I know that quiver takes the component length as input, so the resulting vectors that go into the quiver function should be something like `np.dot(a, [X[i,j], Y[i,j]]) - X[i,j]` for the x-component, where i and j iterate over the ranges.

I can of course program that in a loop, but numpy has sooo many builtin tools to make these vectorized things handy that I'm sure there's a better way.

**edit**: Alright, here's the loop version.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

n=10
X,Y = np.meshgrid( np.arange(-5,5),np.arange(-5,5) )
print("val test", X[5,3])
a = np.array([[0.5,0],[0,1.3]])
U = np.zeros((n,n))
V = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        product = np.dot(a, [X[i,j], Y[i,j]]) #matrix with vector
        U[i,j] = product[0]-X[i,j]  # have to substract the position since quiver accepts magnitudes
        V[i,j] = product[1]-Y[i,j]

Q = plt.quiver( X,Y, U, V)
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like? `a.shape = (2,2), X.shape = (10,5), Y.shape = (10,5)`. I don't get your point...

Comment: Can you show a simple version in a loop (to make it easier to work out what you are trying to do)?

Comment: Done. It's really just a matrix on a vector field, and the results visualized by quivers arrows

Comment: I posted an answer on doing this kind of dot product [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081723/553404), may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do matrix multiplication "manually" using NumPy broadcasting like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5,5), np.arange(-5,5))
a = np.array([[0.5, 0], [0, 1.3]])

U = (a[0,0] - 1)*X + a[0,1]*Y
V = a[1,0]*X + (a[1,1] - 1)*Y

Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
```

or if you want to use `np.dot` you have to flatten your `X` and `Y` arrays and combine them to appropriate shape as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5,5), np.arange(-5,5))
a = np.array([[0.5, 0], [0, 1.3]])

U,V = np.dot(a-np.eye(2), [X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])

Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
```

Comment: Humm, I appreciate that. But that are both extremely limited cases, right? First is a hand-written matrix multiplication. That's pretty hacky and won't work for any higher dimensions etc. And the second is relying in the zeroes.

Comment: Both cases are for 2D. For 3D it should be something like `U,V,W = np.dot(a-np.eye(3), [X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()])`

Answer (score 5):

As the [docs says](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), for multidimensional data `np.mul` (or `@`) works in the following way:

> For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b:
>
> ```
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
> ```

This is not what we want here. However, there are simple alternatives that does not involve flattening-unflattening or manual matrix multiplication: `np.tensordot` and `np.einsum`.

The first is an example taken directly from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum):

> to do a matrix-matrix product with the left-most indices instead of rightmost, you can do `np.einsum('ij...,jk...->ik...', a, b)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5,5), np.arange(-5,5))
a = np.array([[0.5, 0], [0, 1.3]])

U, V = np.einsum('ij...,jk...->ik...', a - np.eye(2), np.array([X, Y]))
Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
```

The second is application of simple `np.tensordot`. We just teach it to sum over second axis (colums) for the first argument and over first axis (rows) for the first argument.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5,5), np.arange(-5,5))
a = np.array([[0.5, 0], [0, 1.3]])

U, V = np.tensordot(a - np.eye(2), np.array([X, Y]), axes=(1, 0))
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with the same question and ended up using the numpy.matrix class. Consider the example below.

```
import numpy as np

>>> transformation_matrix = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1),
...                                   (0, 1, 0, 0),
...                                   (0, 0, 1, 0),
...                                   (0, 0, 0, 1)])
>>> coordinates = np.array([(0,0,0),
...                         (1,0,0)])
>>> coordinates = np.hstack((coordinates, np.ones((len(coordinates), 1))))
>>> coordinates
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

In this case the numpy.matrix class helps. The following code gives the expected result by transposing the coordinates into column vectors and the designated matrix-multiplication overload of the numpy.matrix class.

```
>>> (np.asmatrix(transformation_matrix) * np.asmatrix(coordinates).T).T
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Why did you define them first as arrays, only to convert them to matrices later? You could've done `transformation_matrix = np.matrix([(1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)])`

Comment: @R.Navega That's true, it was just because the OP was operating on `ndarray`s. Note that `asmatrix()` does not make a copy of the data: "Unlike matrix, asmatrix does not make a copy if the input is already a matrix or an ndarray. Equivalent to matrix(data, copy=False)." https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html